# when multiprocessing on django "django.db.utils.OperationalError: disk I/O error"

Tags: python, django

i made crawling and saving the info to django.db function with multiprocessing.
it works fine at first but gives error later.
when i launch stockPriceUpdate() on my desktop, it doesn't occur any errors. but when i launch on my laptop, it works fine at first but laters, it's speed slows down and gives error like below.

Stock is my django model

mycode

```
def stockPriceCrawling(stockTitle):
    
    url = 'http://asp1.krx.co.kr/servlet/krx.asp.XMLSiseEng?code=' + str(stockTitle)
    html = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    stockinfo = soup.select('TBL_StockInfo')[0]
    price = stockinfo['curjuka'].replace(',','')
    highestPrice = stockinfo['highjuka'].replace(',','')
    lowestPrice = stockinfo['lowjuka'].replace(',','')
    tradeVolume = stockinfo['volume'].replace(',','')
    tradeValue = stockinfo['money'].replace(',','')

    print("info : ",' ', price," ",highestPrice," ",lowestPrice," ",tradeVolume," ",tradeValue)
    db.connections.close_all()
    stock= Stock.objects.get(code=stockTitle)
    stock.price = price
    stock.highestPrice = highestPrice
    stock.lowestPrice = lowestPrice
    stock.tradeVolume = tradeVolume
    stock.tradeValue = tradeValue
    stock.save()



def stockPriceUpdate(process=32):
    # start = time.time()

    stocks = Stock.objects.all()
    stockTitles=[]
    for stock in stocks:
        stockTitles.append(str(stock.code))
    
    pool = Pool(32)
    r=pool.map(stockPriceCrawling, stockTitles)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "price_paser.py", line 84, in stockPriceCrawling
    stock.save()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 754, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 792, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 873, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 926, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 803, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1522, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/DAUN/Desktop/swpp/swpp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: disk I/O error
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "price_paser.py", line 166, in <module>
    stockPriceUpdate()
  File "price_paser.py", line 97, in stockPriceUpdate
    r=pool.map(stockPriceCrawling, stockTitles)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
django.db.utils.OperationalError: disk I/O error
```